# Unknown toolbox appears in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I don't know the name of this window, and can't remove it. What it is called and how to remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Those list the hidden/non-visual `Component` objects. Called the ["Component Designer"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8y82386.aspx), it is part of the Windows Form designer. You can't remove it.

Comment: Nor would he want to as it is the only way to select components without UIs from the Design view.

Answer (score 0):

Seems if someone wants to remove that, the only way is to delete all those objects  - but only in case you dont need those objects.